# Android:Sound doesn't play after 24th click

Tags: java, android

So I am a programming beginner and while making a simple soundboard app with 8 buttons, i got a strange problem where it stops playing sound after the 24th button press.Here's the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int i = 0;
    public void playSound(View view){

            switch(view.getId())
            {
                case R.id.button1:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doyouspeakenglish);
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goodevening);
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.howareyou);
                    break;
                case R.id.button5:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ilivein);
                    break;
                case R.id.button6:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mynameis);
                    break;
                case R.id.button7:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.please);
                    break;
                case R.id.button8:
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.welcome);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");
            }
            i++;
        Log.i("klik", Integer.toString(i));
            mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And here's the error message,I'm not allowed to post the image for being a new user so here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEPKC.png)

Comment: Don't use images, please. Copy the entire stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do next time. @cricket_007

Comment: Please [edit] your question so we can see what your error is in text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not releasing the media player resource , so you need to close and release them as well

[`Releasing the MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

```
public void playSound(View view){
        if (null != mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doyouspeakenglish);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goodevening);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.howareyou);
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ilivein);
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mynameis);
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.please);
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.welcome);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");
        }
        i++;
    Log.i("klik", Integer.toString(i));
        mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Annotations on the Media Player:

When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result in an exception.

So before calling MediaPlayer.create again just call

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.release();
```